# SQL sub total and final total query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sum

I need to extend my sql query that currently returns sub totals.  Is there a way to return both sub totals and grand total with this query:

> ```
> SELECT oi.PurchaseID,
> SUM(oi.Quanity * CONVERT(decimal(18,2), p.ItemPrice)) AS sub_total
> FROM vwPurchaseType oi
> JOIN tblColor p ON p.ColorID = oi.ColorID
> WHERE oi.UserID = 1
> GROUP BY oi.PurchaseID
> ```

Can I create another alias for grand total?  I've tried a few different ways and so far I'm leaning toward INSERT the sub_totals into a temp table and returning the value in a stored proc.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify the database you are using, but many databases support the `with rollup` clause for the `group by`:

```
SELECT oi.PurchaseID,
       SUM(oi.Quanity * CONVERT(decimal(18,2), p.ItemPrice)) AS sub_total
FROM vwPurchaseType oi JOIN
     tblColor p
     ON p.ColorID = oi.ColorID
WHERE oi.UserID = 1
GROUP BY oi.PurchaseID WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will add an additional row where the `PurchaseId` is `NULL`.  That has the total in it.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2.  and WITH ROLLUP did it!   Thank you!

Comment: SELECT ISNULL(oi.TypeName,'Total') AS TypeName,
         SUM(oi.Quanity * CONVERT(decimal(18,2), p.ItemPrice)) AS sub_total
    FROM vwPurchaseType oi
    JOIN tblColor p ON p.ColorID = oi.ColorID
    WHERE oi.UserID = 1 AND oi.Paid <> 1
GROUP BY oi.TypeName WITH ROLLUP